# Load Error on C extension of Cached Ruby gem in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gitlab, rubygems, gitlab-ci

For a Rails app, I have a gitlab CI/CD set up with three stages. First stage is caching of gems and assets.

```
cache: &default-cache
  untracked: true
  key: "assets-compile:vendor_ruby:.yarn-cache:tmp_cache_assets_sprockets:v3"
  paths:
    - vendor/ruby/
    - .yarn-cache/
    - public/assets/
    - node_modules/
  policy: pull-push
```

In the next stage, I pull from the cached gems in vendor/ruby folder.

```
testing:
  cache:
    <<: *default-cache
    policy: pull
  stage: test
  image: "ruby:3.0"
  timeout: one hour
  script:
  - apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y -qq nodejs
  - export PATH="/usr/local/bundle/bin:$PATH"
  - bundle config set --local path 'vendor/ruby'
  - RAILS_ENV=test bundle install -j $(nproc)
```

This works well, but for a gem 'ox', throws a LoadError

```
Failure/Error: require 'ox'

LoadError:
  cannot load such file -- ox/ox
# ./vendor/ruby/ruby/3.0.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:38:in `require'
# ./vendor/ruby/ruby/3.0.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.6.6/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:38:in `require'
# ./vendor/ruby/ruby/3.0.0/gems/ox-2.14.11/lib/ox.rb:79:in `<top (required)>'
```

My understanding is that it is unable to load ox.rb which would be created after the C extension is compiled, which is not happening during caching.

How do I solve this?

I tried removing require: false from the Gemfile, but didn't work.

Comment: Do you have `rubygems-update-3.4.4` in your path? I was able to get around this error by removing this gem.